# iOS build not showing anywhere in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode7

I have successfully built and uploaded a new version of an app with Xcode 7.3.1 in OS X 10.11.5, but the build is not showing in iTunes Connect.

After the build process (launched through the "product->archive" menu) the Organizer opens.
There, I choose the build and click on "Upload to App Store..."
So far, everything works as expected.

After the upload, when I refresh the iTunes Connect web page (under the "Activity" tab), I briefly see the new build showing in the list.
If I refresh the page again, some seconds later, the build has disappeared. I can no longer find it anywhere in the iTunes Connect site.
When I try to repeat the process, XCode gives the following error message:

> ERROR ITMS-4238: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a
>   binary upload with build version '2.4' for train '1.5'" at
>   SoftwareAssets/PreReleaseSoftwareAsset

so I have to increase the version number to complete another upload.

I went through this process 3 times, the last one using Application Loader instead of XCode, but the same thing happened all the times.

**Does anyone know why this is happening?**

**What could I do to troubleshoot this problem?**

**What other informations may be useful to further investigate?**

---

**UPDATE**

More than 48 hours have passed since the first upload, still no signs of any builds in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a wrong icon included in the asset catalog.
After 5 days of troubleshooting and ping pong with the Apple support, I was finally pointed in the right direction. All I had to do was replacing an image that was the wrong size.
Done that, all worked as expected.

Comment: I was having the same issue, i was missing the new entitlements file in the project, for example for Push Notifications.

Comment: did you guys mailed apple support ? to get the issue resolved

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can tell you is that it's probably a matter of time. I faced the same issue weeks ago, and between 24 and 48 hours after submitting, my build was finally showing in iTunes Connect.

It's a shame for Apple to make developers wait without informations... But this kind of issue had been reported a lot.